# TreeSet "higher()" returns null when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, null, treeset

I'm currently working on a project for which I use a TreeSet. The set is sorted based on a value. At some point in time, I want to get the right neighbour of a certain "key" value, which does exist and shows up in the debug with the correct values, yet the higher() method still returns null and I have no idea why.

Here is the test code and the debug-output.

```
//  Find the predecessor and successor
SemiCircle lower = status.lower(circle.getLeft());
SemiCircle higher = status.higher(circle.getRight());
```

The status is the TreeSet in this case. This is what it looks like upon searching for the lower and higher value:

```
SemiCircle{parent=0.3 0.8 0.2, isOnLeft=true, key=0.2826}          // This is circle.getLeft()
SemiCircle{parent=0.3 0.8 0.2, isOnLeft=false, key=0.3173}         // This is circle.getRight()
SemiCircle{parent=0.6 0.5 0.3, isOnLeft=true, key=0.3174}
SemiCircle{parent=0.6 0.5 0.3, isOnLeft=false, key=0.8825}
```

As you can see, lower should return null and higher should return the 3th semi-circle in the set, however it just returns null. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: A SemiCircle is half a circle. It keeps the original circle, whether it is the left-half circle or the right and the "key" as explained above.

Comment: *"As you can see"* - sorry, I cannot! I have no idea what `SemiCircle` is (just its name) nor what exactly is meant by *"sorted based on a value"* (based? which value?)

Comment: I updated the question with the printed keys that I use.

Comment: This is entirely based on how the SemiCircle elements are being compared.  Did you create your TreeSet with a custom Comparator?  If so, edit your question and show us the code of that Comparator.  If not, show us the `compareTo` method of SemiCircle.

Comment: The semi-circles in TreeSet are compared based on the key value. They are just sorted from lowest to highest. I'm using TreeSet since I require insert/remove/contain operations to be performed in O(log n)

Comment: If you want to reproduce I'd suggest just keeping a TreeSet with the given keys as elements. That is what the set contains when the "error" happens.

Comment: I resolved the issue. A "NaN" value got introduced after a calculation because of a very small negative number under a square root. This resulted in the higher() function returning null.